# How to create_record at the top of data block in Oracle Forms Builder?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, oracleforms

I would like to be able to create a new record at the top of a datablock?

At the moment I have the following code:

```
    first_record;
    create_record;
```

But this creates the record after the first record.... I would like it at the very top...

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,
WW

Comment: It shouldn't really matter *where* the record appears.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible in forms at the moment.

To accomplish something like this you should make 2 blocks. The first only containing one record to create records. And when you commit something here it will be queried in the second block.